# Why is the path alias I declared not resolved?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, tsconfig-paths

**tl;dr: I am getting error TS2307 when importing a file via an alias path defined in `tsconfig.json`, even though I think the path should be correct.**

---

The directory structure in my Angular/nx/TypeScript project looks like this:

```
project
  |- libs
  |    |- aaa
  |         |- bbb
  |              |- src
  |              |    |- lib
  |              |    |    |- ccc
  |              |    |         |- components
  |              |    |              |- ddd
  |              |    |                   |- ddd.component.ts
  |              |    |- index.ts
  |              |- tsconfig.json
  |- tsconfig.base.json
```

`tsconfig.base.json` defines global paths like this:

```json
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    ...
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      ...
      "@myproject/aaa/bbb": [
        "libs/aaa/bbb/src/index.ts"
      ],
      ...
```

This works as expected - I can import `@myproject/aaa/bbb` and access anything exported from `index.ts`. For example, if I export `DddComponent` (defined in `ddd.component.ts`) from `index.ts`, I can use

`import {DddComponent} from '@myproject/aaa/bbb';`

In `tsconfig.json`, I would like to offer aliases locally inside the aaa/bbb module. Using these aliases, it should be possible to directly access arbitrary files:

```json
{
  "extends": "../../../tsconfig.base.json",
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      ...
      "@lib/ccc/*": [
        "./src/lib/ccc/*"
      ],
      ...
```

---

Now, in `index.ts`, if I write

`import {DddComponent} from './lib/ccc/components/ddd/ddd.component';`

there are no complaints. However, I would like to use my locally defined alias:

`import {DddComponent} from '@lib/ccc/components/ddd/ddd.component';`

(In fact, this is even what WebStorm's auto-completion suggests me to write when I start typing `import {DddComponent}`.)

However, using the latter import statement, the build will fail:

> Error: libs/aaa/bbb/src/index.ts:1:28 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@lib/ccc/components/ddd/ddd.component' or its corresponding type declarations.

**I *think* this should work, yet it doesn't and I do not know why. Is there any way to make my alias work?**

Comment: How do you start the TS compiler?

Comment: @MoritzRingler: By calling `nx serve`. In the main project (the one that is basically the application entry point), there is a `project.json` file, which, in the `"serve"` node, contains the entry `"executor": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server"`. Is that the relevant part of the config to answer your question, or should I look for any other config files/settings?

Answer (score -1):

```
{
  "extends": "../../../tsconfig.base.json",
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      ...
      "@lib/ccc/*": [
        "src/lib/ccc/*" <---- remove the './' prefix
      ],
      ...
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything - WebStorm thinks the path alias is ok, but the TS compiler rejects it with TS2307.